# Rule Learning using SBRL in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, rules

I'm trying to use the Scalable Bayesian Rule Lists Model for creating some rule lists in R. 
Link to package: [SBRL Package R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sbrl/sbrl.pdf)

I read data into a list, split into train and test and plug into the function

```
sbrl_model <- sbrl(data_train,iters=20000, pos_sign="1", neg_sign="0",)
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Error in asMethod(object) : 
column(s) 1, 2, 4, 6 not logical or a factor. Discretize the columns first.
```

When I convert the data_train into a factor and try using:

```
data_train <- sapply(data_train, as.factor)
sbrl_model <- sbrl::sbrl(data_train, iters=20000, pos_sign="1", neg_sign="0",)
```

I get the following error:

```
 Error in data_train$label : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

My data has the following columns:

state, amounts, timestamp, code, risk, vendor, label

The label is 0 or 1. I need to create rules for detecting what data leads to a 1.

I'm new to R so this seems confusing. If I don't convert to factors, it complains, if I do it can't use the "$" operator. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

```
> dput(data_train)
structure(c("PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "MA", "MA", "NH", "NH", "ME", 
"ME", "ME", "VT", "VT", "CT", "CT", "NJ", "NJ", "NY", "NY", "NY", 
"NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", 
"PA", "PA", "DE", "VA", "VA", "VA", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", 
"WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", "WV", 
"WV", "WV", "WV", "GA", "GA", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FL", 
"AL", "AL", "AL", "TN", "TN", "TN", "MS", "MS", "MS", "KY", "KY", 
"KY", "KY", "KY", "KY", "KY", "KY", "KY", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", 
"OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "OH", "IN", 
"IA", "IA", "IA", "IA", "WI", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "MN", "SD", 
"SD", "ND", "ND", "ND", "ND", "ND", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", 
"MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "MO", "KS", "KS", "KS", "KS", 
"KS", "KS", "KS", "16441", "92946", "8970", "19937", "94589", 
"50615", "75915", "50005", "23037", "14835", "83678", "66263", 
"60818", "82760", "42137", "32888", "35385", "20242", "98269", 
"16216", "76562", "49327", "30699", "1866", "91301", "75125", 
"34016", "88673", "78612", "85008", "91030", "57276", "96772", 
"79568", "59489", "14154", "71655", "78163", "41673", "19942", 
"19364", "34004", "79349", "1611", "8875", "19673", "5422", "42395", 
"11899", "26967", "73499", "79916", "71015", "73640", "39759", 
"7735", "84853", "31662", "43183", "44787", "79001", "82999", 
"17031", "88109", "62215", "56040", "66592", "59148", "20786", 
"30106", "46561", "9125", "83512", "60031", "65233", "49512", 
"8893", "46275", "11362", "29867", "61573", "46363", "91510", 
"19267", "45554", "41193", "54267", "8045", "28089", "62450", 
"69082", "66685", "80769", "15446", "62589", "42875", "74723", 
"2934", "18540", "96540", "60812", "50636", "90924", "60556", 
"90009", "15287", "35529", "28702", "82102", "96967", "5296", 
"64804", "48743", "10867", "60914", "83678", "77883", "97631", 
"97175", "48103", "63128", "46774", "18285", "74512", "69313", 
"80414", "32394", "51103", "51155", "28672", "38460", "89024", 
"49443", "2016-01-23 12:14:07", "2016-01-17 19:22:37", "2016-01-23 22:41:32", 
"2016-01-27 09:58:34", "2016-01-30 08:40:06", "2016-01-28 01:41:40", 
"2016-01-27 08:22:27", "2016-01-28 00:13:48", "2016-01-20 12:31:12", 
"2016-01-17 08:25:30", "2016-01-28 13:01:36", "2016-01-20 12:10:46", 
"2016-01-25 07:32:01", "2016-01-23 02:13:11", "2016-01-24 11:14:46", 
"2016-01-16 20:59:35", "2016-01-19 20:12:58", "2016-01-19 06:38:06", 
"2016-01-27 10:15:48", "2016-01-26 14:00:30", "2016-01-28 01:54:45", 
"2016-01-27 05:43:58", "2016-01-25 22:07:06", "2016-01-18 09:58:05", 
"2016-01-20 05:56:54", "2016-01-26 08:05:32", "2016-01-28 14:18:45", 
"2016-01-22 06:25:48", "2016-01-27 18:05:50", "2016-01-16 11:33:47", 
"2016-01-22 03:31:52", "2016-01-23 05:41:37", "2016-01-27 00:55:22", 
"2016-01-16 17:19:51", "2016-01-18 10:05:42", "2016-01-22 10:20:16", 
"2016-01-26 21:07:20", "2016-01-17 19:12:00", "2016-01-19 17:59:45", 
"2016-01-28 08:50:18", "2016-01-16 09:31:52", "2016-01-24 14:50:13", 
"2016-01-17 14:02:36", "2016-01-20 17:08:29", "2016-01-25 16:42:03", 
"2016-01-19 04:18:27", "2016-01-20 03:05:13", "2016-01-26 23:34:33", 
"2016-01-26 13:44:56", "2016-01-16 07:09:41", "2016-01-26 06:43:12", 
"2016-01-26 20:22:25", "2016-01-23 05:58:38", "2016-01-19 23:21:00", 
"2016-01-16 08:36:10", "2016-01-30 01:21:00", "2016-01-23 11:10:06", 
"2016-01-27 15:29:30", "2016-01-30 15:50:38", "2016-01-19 08:32:33", 
"2016-01-19 18:18:02", "2016-01-21 14:20:47", "2016-01-17 13:19:59", 
"2016-01-20 05:49:06", "2016-01-16 15:54:17", "2016-01-21 09:15:42", 
"2016-01-16 07:32:39", "2016-01-28 03:49:00", "2016-01-26 00:19:56", 
"2016-01-25 10:29:44", "2016-01-23 06:26:45", "2016-01-29 08:03:34", 
"2016-01-22 14:24:34", "2016-01-16 18:44:43", "2016-01-26 00:00:51", 
"2016-01-20 17:38:03", "2016-01-17 22:38:47", "2016-01-30 10:12:01", 
"2016-01-21 17:00:43", "2016-01-22 08:43:30", "2016-01-27 12:04:58", 
"2016-01-25 21:09:40", "2016-01-27 16:35:42", "2016-01-27 20:09:03", 
"2016-01-27 09:52:40", "2016-01-26 16:12:37", "2016-01-28 16:57:29", 
"2016-01-30 13:48:47", "2016-01-30 19:15:03", "2016-01-24 19:33:56", 
"2016-01-28 06:57:55", "2016-01-22 18:21:40", "2016-01-16 02:54:57", 
"2016-01-23 08:18:44", "2016-01-20 13:47:54", "2016-01-24 16:23:39", 
"2016-01-24 19:15:09", "2016-01-22 14:59:14", "2016-01-30 10:21:43", 
"2016-01-27 11:54:39", "2016-01-30 15:19:59", "2016-01-24 19:21:48", 
"2016-01-27 07:20:14", "2016-01-25 07:11:55", "2016-01-24 22:33:42", 
"2016-01-26 14:30:57", "2016-01-16 13:12:46", "2016-01-28 11:25:45", 
"2016-01-28 14:44:25", "2016-01-23 03:25:10", "2016-01-26 13:45:49", 
"2016-01-19 06:14:21", "2016-01-25 22:12:29", "2016-01-25 12:13:07", 
"2016-01-22 23:56:39", "2016-01-24 07:51:51", "2016-01-24 10:50:30", 
"2016-01-21 07:02:41", "2016-01-21 09:52:54", "2016-01-26 22:35:52", 
"2016-01-19 06:48:13", "2016-01-19 15:18:21", "2016-01-20 12:20:37", 
"2016-01-16 07:04:34", "2016-01-24 10:20:05", "2016-01-25 09:01:09", 
"2016-01-21 17:02:29", "2016-01-21 11:52:00", "2016-01-27 19:39:16", 
"2016-01-19 18:33:35", "2016-01-18 06:00:23", "2016-01-17 01:27:11", 
"2016-01-18 10:27:57", "3355", "4935", "5454", "9555", "5938", 
"5855", "4888", "3885", "8533", "4359", "5339", "5554", "5894", 
"8598", "5448", "9535", "3495", "3358", "3485", "3344", "8489", 
"8553", "3354", "5889", "5948", "8455", "5988", "5595", "9354", 
"8485", "4559", "4838", "5585", "5585", "8554", "8598", "5535", 
"5355", "5844", "3485", "5885", "8833", "8558", "9889", "9885", 
"8555", "3938", "8343", "8558", "5484", "3558", "3545", "8394", 
"9933", "3853", "4598", "3855", "5845", "5588", "5495", "8585", 
"9584", "3385", "8858", "9445", "8488", "8558", "5838", "5848", 
"8845", "8848", "8945", "4599", "8585", "8858", "4598", "5358", 
"5395", "9485", "4893", "4455", "8493", "9358", "5395", "8958", 
"5888", "8888", "8555", "4885", "3538", "8998", "4445", "4838", 
"9885", "3559", "5584", "9594", "8558", "3844", "5434", "8558", 
"9898", "4395", "9585", "3858", "4858", "5895", "9383", "9858", 
"8385", "5585", "4884", "8359", "8893", "3484", "8383", "5338", 
"3544", "9859", "9454", "3539", "3583", "8455", "5983", "4345", 
"4943", "5548", "8353", "8993", "8594", "8994", "3958", "3989", 
"W sWn  ae", "o gogynh ", " ntsnagWe", "aiatteaav", "shiytWngg", 
"vvmthethW", "Wynhvrrht", "tttnheviv", "itg oiWhe", "a enotisn", 
"ehaothe h", "stmeathng", "i emranth", "tersggtnh", "oeiehvhh ", 
"sngeeetvg", "gyyhWatge", "ritnhengs", "etihi s e", "aoeertyWn", 
"eeytitys ", "nmnmegome", "n vitsnot", " h i eoht", "ahghtangh", 
"ehgn hynh", "ener aeig", "t niaat g", "agtWh eah", "vehi amae", 
"enhnnn hg", "ennWhgnea", "tay hnaah", "igntyvrtv", "niesehahn", 
" eoavongr", "hi ehhimm", "yovgianWi", "e tnehngg", "eyehtte n", 
"at nimnrg", "enesgennW", "mhahnhyet", "tt amtgna", "hehtsoish", 
"hyvtanggv", "et v nssn", "inhnahe h", "onahhraWn", "mn iiahsy", 
" mymisnsg", "magWoshgr", "i t eneve", "nghy naen", "eyhsyehea", 
"i ihntvea", "ththnWyri", "vntv yran", "ynaieere ", "yenre htW", 
"ehyWga g ", "ngeagmenh", " nW ytito", "ermhaagvr", "eeWvtr eg", 
"etreaehon", "thtWyerme", "hnveWnrta", "htmr ohee", "stitnthsi", 
"snthhWh a", "ehhth iny", "shgoovema", " mseynWee", "netmiitnt", 
"nvi   eao", "t  seWWay", "yngnerarm", "ggenitaeh", "n eaogiag", 
"mitnetmnh", "not sine ", "ghmhnyhne", "eattnatgh", "vhatngtts", 
"tntmegten", "hreyatert", "ggmneheri", "g y en he", "igrt ggrh", 
"mehnssith", "gigstgnym", "iathWh ii", "h atynin ", "eiieWmetg", 
"noyggtive", " iotneng ", "oveieteen", "shnagrhti", "itooo aWv", 
"toreytnny", " henaaWvn", "shehnrh W", "ttrntehgi", "oWait tn ", 
"hhshhnthh", "nogeamnme", "iraah thh", "eto ngvgr", "Wno tseie", 
"ehnato eW", "anservnhn", "htsyyoarv", "n  aththe", "vaneav  h", 
"tmttvniri", "gtmhgrtgv", "h tmtnvgt", " nnaiygnr", "httot ami", 
"hehnheeis", "ihtaneito", "eogh h yg", "eWgeiimv ", "sgnyisihh", 
"r  ngangW", "teihyaeee", "hrytWnhgi", "nniaeavmh", "iotrWehn ", 
" gnvgorht", "vyinaaen ", "tgniiseae", "14", "86", "51", "54", 
"90", "15", "23", "49", "6", "45", "65", "55", "53", "52", "55", 
"84", "74", "74", "45", "88", "4", "76", "65", "41", "77", "40", 
"66", "39", "80", "6", "35", "56", "40", "57", "90", "66", "59", 
"30", "98", "31", "55", "12", "29", "67", "85", "16", "94", "87", 
"61", "55", "94", "95", "68", "10", "45", "41", "93", "55", "13", 
"12", "80", "45", "59", "23", "45", "1", "68", "89", "86", "68", 
"46", "50", "57", "78", "85", "40", "53", "26", "67", "75", "29", 
"78", "91", "35", "37", "10", "90", "36", "9", "14", "36", "31", 
"5", "57", "90", "65", "48", "80", "20", "13", "92", "62", "72", 
"71", "52", "50", "16", "92", "79", "9", "97", "78", "69", "50", 
"84", "96", "82", "95", "44", "2", "76", "13", "1", "16", "65", 
"75", "91", "30", "60", "62", "97", "86", "82", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1"
), .Dim = c(133L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("state", "amounts", 
"timestamp", "code", "vendor", "risk", "label")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you tried to turn the entire data.frame into a factor, not just 1 column. That resulted in an atomic vector full of junk, hence the error message you received.

This works:

```
data_train           <- as.data.frame(data_train)
data_train$state     <- as.factor(data_train$state)
data_train$amounts   <- as.factor(as.character(data_train$amounts))
data_train$timestamp <- as.factor(data_train$timestamp)
data_train$code      <- as.factor(data_train$code)
data_train$vender    <- as.factor(data_train$vender)
data_train$label     <- as.factor(data_train$label)

sbrl_model <- sbrl(data_train, iters=20000, pos_sign="1", neg_sign="0",)
```

> ```
> create itemset ... 
> set transactions ...[48 item(s), 8 transaction(s)] done [0.00s].
> sorting and recoding items ... [48 item(s)] done [0.00s].
> creating sparse bit matrix ... [48 row(s), 8 column(s)] done [0.00s].
> writing  ... [48 set(s)] done [0.00s].
> Creating S4 object  ... done [0.00s].
> Eclat
>
> parameter specification:
>  tidLists support minlen maxlen            target   ext
>     FALSE     0.1      1      1 frequent itemsets FALSE
>
> algorithmic control:
>  sparse sort verbose
>       7   -2    TRUE
>
> Absolute minimum support count: 12 
>
> create itemset ... 
> set transactions ...[469 item(s), 125 transaction(s)] done [0.00s].
> sorting and recoding items ... [4 item(s)] done [0.00s].
> creating sparse bit matrix ... [4 row(s), 125 column(s)] done [0.00s].
> writing  ... [4 set(s)] done [0.00s].
> Creating S4 object  ... done [0.00s].
> ```

Comment: Thanks! That was careless of me.

Comment: surely because they are all being converted to a factor you could use `lapply(data_train, function(x) as.factor(as.character(x)))`?

Comment: @Joiya550 No problem, glad it works. Good question btw +1.

Comment: @zacdav They aren't necessarily all factor. Could be logical. Also there's another column that's numeric which it didn't complain about, so I left that as numeric.

Comment: @Hack-R Wouldn't my suggestion still handle all cases fine?

Comment: @zacdav It would incorrectly convert logical or numerics to factor which is a bad thing.

Comment: @Hack-R I only suggested this because having a separate line for each column seems a bit ludicrous.

Comment: Does anyone know how to access the final rule list? Thanks!